# Cambiar imagen y nombre usuario Navigation Drawer desde aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android, y no consigo encontrar nada que me explique cómo puedo hacer para que el usuario, una vez que instala la aplicación en su móvil, pueda elegir una imagen de perfil que tenga guardada en su móvil y cambiar el nombre de usuario (pulsando sobre el icono de perfil de la cabecera del Navigation Drawer). 
También me valdría que se vinculase con Gmail y directamente insertase el nombre y la foto de Gmail.

[image: Navigation Drawer]

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Favor de agregar el código.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada y probablemente duplicada de esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163179/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-hacer-que-mi-c%C3%B3digo-cambie-la-imagen-de-un-navigation-drawer/200403#200403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero necesitas obtener la instancia del header de tu navdrawer.

```
View navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

despues inicializas tus variables y realizas el findViewById() pero desde el view del header que obtuvimos antes

```
nombre = navHeader.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_userName);
```

y listo, acordate de llamar al getHeaderView() dentro del método onCreate() y después de iniciar y hookear tu nav

Comment: Funciona! Muchisimas gracias! :)