# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi código cambie la imagen de un Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android

Lo que necesito es que el código coja un objeto y cambie la imagen que aparece por defecto al crear un navigation drawer. El problema es que al intentar cambiarlo me da este error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference.

Estoy tocando la clase `NavigationDrawer`. La clase recibe un objeto de otra clase (ya he comprobado que el objeto se crea correctamente no sea null). `textViewDrawerFoto` es la imagen del navigation drawer y `textViewDrawerNombre` es el texto que aparece debajo.

Si precisan más información pidanmelo por favor.

[image: Imagen del navigation drawer]

Este es mi código:

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, InicioFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    ImageView miImageViewDrawerFoto;
    TextView miTextViewDrawerNombre;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Fragment fragment = new InicioFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_drawer, fragment).commit();

        miImageViewDrawerFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDrawerFoto);
        miTextViewDrawerNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDrawerNombre);

            Alumno alum = (Alumno) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("User");

            miTextViewDrawerNombre.setText(alum.getNombre() + " " + alum.getApellidos());
            try {
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(alum.getFoto_perfil()).error(R.drawable.user).into(miImageViewDrawerFoto);
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                miImageViewDrawerFoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
            }   
    }
```

Comment: Agregué una respuesta para esto y un tutorial para que sea de ayuda a los miembros de la comunidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando estuve desarrollando una aplicación para mi proyecto, era fundamental el modificar esos dos datos, para personalización de la aplicación.

Creo que el error está en no estás tomando los *widgets* desde el `NavigationView` con el que estás operando. A partir de ahí, recogiendo lo que deseas con el método `getHeaderView(0)`, es cuando puedes empezar a buscar cada *widget* de forma individual, tanto para texto como para imagen.

Adjunto el método con el que auné las dos operaciones:

```
    public void setDataToNavigationDrawer(User user) {
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        TextView txtV_Username = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.txtV_username);
        TextView txtV_Email = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.txtV_email);
        txtV_Username.setText(user.getUsername());
        txtV_Email.setText(user.getEmail());
    }
```

Comment: Lo he probado y ahora sí me sale. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una duda setDataToNavigationDrawer del método que tienes es la clase de las variables y sus parametros tanto como los get y set.

Answer (score 1):

#### ¿Cómo cambiar la imagen y textos principales en un Navigation Drawer?

Primeramente debes ubicar en que archivo se encuentran estos elementos, para obtener sus referencias y posteriormente cambiar sus propiedades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si usaste Android Studio y seleccionaste como Activity principal "Navigation Drawer Activity" generalmente los elementos a modificar se encuentran dentro del archivo `nav_header_main.xml`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Primeramente obtenemos la referencia del `NavigationView`

```
   NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

y posteriormente las referencias de los elementos, toma en cuenta que para obtener las referencias los elementos deben tener definida un id

```
    /* Change properties in NavigationView*/
   TextView txtName = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
   TextView txtEmail = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
   ImageView imageView  = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    String urlImage = "https://url_imagen.png";
    //Agrega una nueva imagen desde una url usando Picasso.
    Picasso.get().load(urlImage).into(imageView);
    //Agrega nuevo nombre
    txtName.setText("Jorgesys");
    //Agrega nuevo e-mail
    txtEmail.setText("jorgesys@jorgesys.com");
```

también puedes asignar una imagen desde tu proyecto ubicada en el directorio `/drawable` usando `Picasso` de esta forma:

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.my_imagen).into(imageView);
```

o sin usar ninguna library de esta forma:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_imagen);
```

al cambiar las propiedades podemos asignar la imagen o textos deseados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego [un **ejemplo** para que sea de utilidad a la comunidad](https://github.com/Jorgesys/NavigationView-properties.).